# Aptana IDE not supporting laravel

Tags: php, laravel, aptana3

I am trying to move from core PHP to some framework. I am trying to use LARAVEL as I got good reviews for it. I am able to set it up and can see the welcome screen as given in the tutorial.

The problem is after I import the project in Aptana, the moment I open any file it starts showing syntax errors. It seems to me that Aptana is not supporting Laravel however I am not sure.

Tried to search how can i make it work. Can anyone help? In case I need to move some other IDE can anyone please suggest which IDE I should go for?

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper ?

Comment: yes i checked it out... saw the video as well but the video was for phpstorm . i tried the same steps but nothing worked out :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are not syntax errors that you're seeing. If that is really the case, there's either something wrong with your installation of Laravel or Aptana doesn't know what valid PHP looks like...

Comment: well i have developed core php projects in aptana so i am pretty much sure aptana does know about valid php but i guess it doesn't have support for laravel by default because actually there is no syntax error in those files.